Write a datetime to the database using model.DateTimeField() in Python Django, the UTC timezone is not correctly displayed in the database
settings.py
TIME_ZONE = "Asia/Taipei"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

models.py
from django.db import models

class ApiLog(models.Model):
    endpoint = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    request_body = models.TextField()
    response_body = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'api_log'
        managed = False  # 若資料表為手動建立，將 managed 設為 False



    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.method} {self.endpoint} at {self.timestamp}"

views.py
def simple_api(request):
    endpoint = request.path
    method = request.method
    request_body = request.body.decode('utf-8') if request.body else ""

    if method == 'GET':
        response_data = {'message': 'This is a GET request'}
    elif method == 'POST':
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            response_data = {'message': 'Data received', 'data': data}
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            response_data = {'error': 'Invalid JSON format'}
    else:
        response_data = {'error': 'Method not allowed'}

    response_body = json.dumps(response_data)

    # def UTC+8 
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
    # get utc+8 time
    current_utc_plus_8_time = timezone.now().astimezone(tz)

    print("Current UTC+8 Time:", current_utc_plus_8_time)

    # record ApiLog
    ApiLog.objects.create(
        endpoint=endpoint,
        method=method,
        request_body=request_body,
        response_body=response_body,
        timestamp=current_utc_plus_8_time
    )

    return JsonResponse(response_data)

Based on this design, I expect the recorded timestamp in the database to be in the format “yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.ssssss+08:00.”
However, when querying directly with a SELECT statement in the database, the result is converted to UTC+0. I’ve tried several methods to resolve this issue.
For example:

In Java, using mybatis

mapper
@Mapper
public interface ApiLogMapper {

  @Insert("INSERT INTO api_log (endpoint, method, request_body, response_body, timestamp) " +
      "VALUES (#{endpoint}, #{method}, #{requestBody}, #{responseBody}, #{timestamp})")
  @Options(useGeneratedKeys = true, keyProperty = "id")
  void insertApiLog(ApiLog apiLog);
}

controller
  @PostMapping("/message")
  public ResponseEntity<String> handleMessage(@RequestBody String message) {
    // def UTC+8  OffsetDateTime
    OffsetDateTime dateTimeUTC8 = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.ofHours(8));
    
    String response = "message";  
    // record ApiLog 
    ApiLog log = new ApiLog();
    log.setEndpoint("/api/chatbox/message");
    log.setMethod("POST");
    log.setRequestBody(message);
    log.setResponseBody(response);
    log.setTimestamp(dateTimeUTC8);
    System.out.println(log.getTimestamp());
    apiLogMapper.insertApiLog(log);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
  }

this method correctly shows UTC+8 results in the database.

In Python, using a SQL script for insertion also displays results in UTC+8.


def log_api_call(endpoint: str, method: str, request_body: str,
    response_body: str):
  connection = get_connection()
  cursor = connection.cursor()
  # def utc+8 timezone
  timezone_utc8 = pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
  utc8_time = datetime.now(timezone_utc8)

  print(utc8_time)


  query = """
    INSERT INTO api_log (endpoint, method, request_body, response_body, timestamp)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ? AT TIME ZONE 'Taipei Standard Time' )
    """
  cursor.execute(query, (
  endpoint, method, request_body, response_body, utc8_time))
  connection.commit()
  cursor.close()
  connection.close()


@app.post("/example-endpoint")
async def example_endpoint(request: Request):
  request_body = await request.json()

  response_body = {"message": "This is a response"}

  response_body_str = json.dumps(response_body)

  # record APILog
  log_api_call(
      endpoint="/example-endpoint",
      method="POST",
      request_body=json.dumps(request_body),
      response_body=response_body_str
  )

  return response_body

more information:
using mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-lates
TZ=Asia/Taipei
SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AS CurrentDateTimeWithOffset;

CurrentDateTimeWithOffset    |
-----------------------------+
2024-11-14 10:25:44.588 +0800|

SELECT CURRENT_TIMEZONE() AS TimeZone;

TimeZone          |
------------------+
(UTC+08:00) Taipei|

table
create table api_log
(
    id            bigint identity
        primary key,
    endpoint      nvarchar(255),
    method        nvarchar(10),
    request_body  nvarchar(max),
    response_body nvarchar(max),
    timestamp     datetimeoffset
)
go

Is there a way to achieve this in the Django framework?
As described in the question, I expect the time displayed in the database to match the UTC time zone in which it was written.
if AP UTC+8 Time is 2024-11-14 09:53:31.916319**+08:00**
,then Select DB timestamp must is 2024-11-14 09:53:31.916319**+08:00**

In the interest of ruling out that this is an X/Y problem, can I ask why you need this? The whole point of converting to UTC is so that you don't have to store the timezone on the timestamp itself - what you are asking for is maybe doable, but it's an explicit anti-pattern.

I remember running into a similar problem a while ago using a Postgres DB. Postgres seems to always convert timestamps to UTC and return them in the timezone of your session. Django on the other hand always retrieves the timestamps in UTC and converts them to the local timezone, if I remember corrrectly.
Do you also use a Postgres DB?

@Vegard This table will be used by multiple different systems simultaneously. Users expect to see the timestamp in the table (e.g., SELECT timestamp FROM api_log) uniformly in UTC+8. The reason for this is that one of the systems currently uses Java for implementation, and its output aligns with the example I provided in the first item.

@Tim This case uses MSSQL, but I also tried the same implementation with PostgreSQL. The result was similarly converted to UTC+0 time.

Maybe I am not understanding the heart of the issue, but can you not convert it to the proper timezone after fetching it from the DB? If they expect UTC +8 uniformly, for example, all of them can just convert from UTC +0 to UTC +8? Or if all the systems operate in UTC +8, turn off timezone-awareness in Django and store the local timestamp - which should then be UTC +8 natively.

@Vegard I think the core of the issue lies in the fact that dateoffset is used to record timezone information along with the timestamp. For the users, what they expect is to record both the system’s current time (UTC+8) and its timezone in the database. This means that what they see in the database should reflect UTC+8. However, when using Django’s model to generate database records, there is a discrepancy (although for developers, this actually makes no difference, since Django will automatically convert the retrieved time back to UTC+8 when reading it).

I do understand the expectation, but I am wondering about its basis. Whether the database contains timezone info or not seems to be inconsequential to the use-case (unless I am missing something), as any user can just convert from +0 to +8 after data retrieval and then always be assured to have received the correct timestamp? Is it an ease-of-use thing where some users are inspecting data "directly" in the database?

When you store a date/time in Django, it is always converted to utc+0 time.
This appears to be intentional and may result in conversion from Django's time zone to the utc time set in the settings.
from django.utils import timezone

timezone.now() # utc +0 time
timezone.localtime(timezone.now()) # utc +{timzeon in settings} time


I have tested several methods, including overriding the save method in models.py to process the timestamp before writing it to the database via super.save. However, this still could not prevent UTC from being converted to UTC+0. Therefore, I personally suspect that this behavior is likely inherent to Django’s design.

Django stores the time utc+0 in the database, and it is impossible to change it.
Instead, you need to adjust the time to call from DB through the time zone package.
